# how do i correctly set up a parameterized information link in spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

Also posted on super users:

I'm a spotfire novice trying to create a parameterized info link. Ultimate goal is to create a default template that may be customized to return specific rows in a very large table. I've not been able to cobble together enough information from online searches to get me from point A to Z.

Spotfire version is 7.11 on an Oracle 11.2 SE DB.

Currently I've got a date/time prompt in the info link that will be global to all users. What I need is to be able to further filter to 1 of 2 columns (one is real, the other a string) in order to minimize loading times. There are 17 other on-demand tables that are related to the main one. Limiting the initial query will greatly speed up performance.

In information designer for the information link, if I edit the SQL in the WHERE and explicitly define the value or string for the column, I get the rows I want. When I try to define it using an input parameter (?ParamName), I either get nothing when I reload or get asked to input a parameter "for testing".

Q1: In the document properties for the analysis, I've been adding in properties that I assume is supposed to get picked up by the query.
- What part do scripts play in passing this variable to the SQL?
- Do I just need to define a value for a property name or include a IronPython script? - If script is required, can I just define the parameter to pass?

Q2: In the info link SQL, what is the correct syntax for defining the parameter variable depending on the type (real v string)? If I use a string, I need to include LIKE in order to pick up the desired rows. If I use a real, is it possible to define it as a list of values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Though not exactly clear from your description, I think you should be able to accomplish your goals using the "Load on demand" dialog that is accessed either when you add your data table to your analysis, or subsequently using the Data Table Properties>Type of Data>Settings dialog.

Spotfire uses this dialog to dynamically modify your SQL. Thus, you do not need to explicitly include the LIKE statement in your SQL. Spotfire will add it in based on what you define in the On-Demand settings. For example, you could have an Input Field where you type a constraint that will be stored as a Document Property and then refer to that Document Property in your On-Demand settings to control the table loading.

Comment: Thanks.  I did solve this a couple days ago.  Changing my main table to load on demand was the key I was missing.  After that it was obvious that I could set the WHERE conditions to control loading by the properties I set in the document.  Everything online I found led me to believe I needed to learn ironpython scripting and setting up configuration blocks to make this work.  Not nearly as involved.